# visual c++ 6.0 code for implementing enter command

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, keyboard

How do I implement the "enter" command in a Visual C++ 6.0 project using the MFC application wizard(exe)?

It would be somewhat modification of the following code for finding the size of the entered string:

```cpp
void CCentredView::OnDraw(CDC*pDC)
{
    CCentredDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);

    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(&rect);

    int x= rect.Width()/2;
    int y= rect.Height()/2;

    CSize size = pDC->GetTextExtent(pDoc->StringData);
    //...
}
```

Now to get code for enter command we have to check if the struck key is a carriage return,  `\r`, and if so move to the next line by adding the height of the text string to the `y` variable to skip to the next text line on the screen.

But, I am not getting how to implement the code!

Comment: It is not clear what you ask. If you want to determine the size of a rectangle that will hold the text, I recommend you to use CDC::DrawText (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a6x7y2a4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) passing DT_CALCRECT flag. Please provide more code, so that we understand how your x, y, and size variables are used.

Answer (score 0):

Homework question?

Either way, catch the return key press by filtering for WM_KEYDOWN with VK_RETURN in PreTranslateMessage. Do your carriage return inserting there.